# How to handle browser closing popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, firefoxdriver

In one of my scenario I am filling the form but not submitting due to my requirement. Now I am closing the browser but while closing browser it is browser an alert by saying "Are you sure .... ". How to handle this popup in firefox.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add an event listener to the "close" event via JS that confirms the alert if triggered? That would be my solution for this problem since the injected code stays alive even after the WebDriver is killed off.

Comment: Could you please share the sample code...It sounds it  helps

Comment: What is the purpose of the test? What exactly are you testing? How do you close the browser? If you use driver.quit() I am not sure you will be able to interact with the browser in any way since quit() performs some internal "destruction" work except of just closing window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're at least 3 ways to handle this case.

- Refresh the page and then dismiss the dialog if the driver supports it :

```
driver.refresh();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.quit();
```

- Setup the targeted driver to ignore the dialog :

```
// Chrome
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Firefox
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true)
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

- Inject some JavaScript into the page to prevent the dialog :

```
string JS_DISABLE_UNLOAD_DIALOG = "Object.defineProperty(BeforeUnloadEvent.prototype, 'returnValue', { get:function(){}, set:function(){} });"
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(JS_DISABLE_UNLOAD_DIALOG);
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Hey @Florent, Thanks for your soultions. 2nd solution worked for me like a charm!...Thank you soo much

Comment: All of them are working with the latest version of Firefox. Though it should be `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` instead of `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();` for the first one.

Comment: May be true.In my scenario 2nd option is working fine and 3rd option is not working for me. 1st option is not suitable to my scenario

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? I'd like to find-out why the 3rd one is not working. Do you have a frame in the page?

Comment: Firefox version - 59.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: could you please help me with this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33338/unable-to-enter-16-digit-credit-card-number-in-ie-browser-using-sendkeys-method

Answer (score 1):

I have one test that results in a modal dialog popping up with a yes/no question.

I always was to press Yes and the code I use is....

```
webDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: this popup is appearing after webDriver.quit() call. Hence I can't use above code as it trough invalid session exception

Comment: How about unchecking the 'warn me' message so it no longer appears?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found other people having [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758813/selenium-close-a-window-with-a-confirmation-alert-c-sharp).
So I would suggest the same to you:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.onbeforeunload = null;");
```

Use this code before `driver.quit();` to avoid closure popups.

Comment: This is not working..Do we have any alternative solution for this.

Comment: I suggest looking at the answers in the link I posted. There are other solutions that might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`WebDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();`  --> for accepting the alert and

`WebDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();` --> for dismissing the alert.