# Unable to enter 16 digit credit card number in IE browser using sendKeys method of Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ie

As per my requirement I have to enter credit card number which is `4111 1111 1111 1111`.

I am trying with `sendKeys()`, it is working in all browsers except `IE` browser.

When it is trying to enter the number in IE browser its only entering 1 or 2 digits. Not sure why it is happening with IE browser only.

Any ideas?

Comment: Call sendKeys for each digit.

Comment: As @FlorentB suggests, the IE interface is slow and in some ways buggy.  Write a sendkeys wrapper that sends the keystrokes one-a-a-time if the browser is IE.

Comment: Obviously, the solution is drop support for IE. =)

Comment: @FlorentB. You should make an answer =)

Answer (score 3):

Use **JavaScriptExecutor** instead of the `SendKeys`:

```
String cardNum= "4111111111111111";
WebElement inputField= driver.findElement(By.id("cardnum"));

JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[1].value = arguments[0]; ", cardNum, inputField);
```

Comment: By writing the value directly, you are no longer simulating a user input. The element could be disabled, not interactable and it doesn't emit the events expected the page like `keydown`, `keyup`, `input`, `change`, `focus`). Thus this should never be used in test.

Comment: @FlorentB. I guess it depends on what you're testing. I think your point is well articulated, but I also think never is a strong word.

Comment: @corsiKa, a test is supposed to validate a behavior, not just work, especially with an e2e test. So in this case never is just the right word. That is if you want to write a useful test. Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that injecting some JS in the page should never be done. I'm saying it should never be done as presented in this solution since it doesn't assert the interactibility nor emit any event.